# Respond.js not working locally - Support for media queries in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, localhost, media-queries, twitter-bootstrap-3, respond.js

I am writing a html page using bootstrap3 template and including the respond.js in that, but when I run it on IE8, it gives me error "Access is denied" in console.
I am using this to make IE8 support media queries. I have tried a lot of things as given on forums, but no luck. Does respond.js works locally or we need to run on a localhost/web server?

Respond.js link - https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <div class="main-cont">         
    </div>
</div>        
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS** - main.css

```
.main-cont {background:#2d3a42; height:100px;}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just managed to make respond.js run on IE8 for media queries support , by running on localhost. If simply the html file opened, it does not help.

Comment: I actually linked to a respond.js file using an absolute link in the header to one residing on someone else's web server but I still get the "access is denied" error when viewing the site locally. Is that not one work-around to getting it to work without a local webserver?

Comment: Well, I am not too sure if this would be a work around. I just tried running on local host and it started working.

Comment: This does not work for me -- access is denied locally in localhost or if I use remote scripts.

Answer (score 9):

Per the [Respond.js Docs](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)...

> "Due to security restrictions, some browsers may not allow this script to work on file:// urls (because it uses xmlHttpRequest). Run it on a web server."

Specifically, "Respond.js re-requests the CSS files using Ajax and parses the text response," which is where IE's local security policy is blocking you. Another user elsewhere suggested [changing the security settings in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13315176/2567232), but I can't confirm that solution since my copy of IE8 doesn't permit me to change those settings.

Oh, and to save you the trouble, I already tested and confirmed that using ajaxSetup() method in jQuery to set "isLocal" property to "true" won't overcome the local restriction in IE.